# When separation in $L^1$ is possible?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem, reference-request

Let $A$, $B$ be disjoint convex closed subsets of the Banach space $L^1[0,1]$. Assume additionally that $A$ is bounded and $A$, $B$ are closed under convergence in measure. Then there exists a closed hyperplane, which strictly separates $A$ and $B$.

This follows almost immediately from the Komlós lemma (if the distance between $A$ and $B$ is positive, then usual Hahn-Banach theorem works, if not, let $a_n\in A$, $b_n\in B$ be so that $\|a_n-b_n\|\rightarrow 0$, by Komlós lemma we may without loss of generality suppose that $c_n:=(a_1+\dots+a_n)/n$, $d_n:=(b_1+\dots+b_n)/n$ converge in measure to $c\in A$, $d\in B$ respectively, but $\|c_n-d_n\|\rightarrow 0$, hence $c=d$, a contradiction.)

Two questions are:

1) This looks like a very classical subject, what is appropriate reference?

2) Are there some weaker general assumptions for the existence of separator in $L^1$ or maybe in more general spaces?